# catching all of module's exceptions

Tags: python

I have a script and keep getting different exceptions thrown. Right now, my code is written like:

```
from requests.exceptions import InvalidURL, TooManyRedirects, InvalidSchema

try:
    #do thing
except (InvalidURL, TooManyRedirects, InvalidSchema):
   pass
```

But requests has a lot of exceptions and typing them all out is laborious. Is there a way to do something along the lines of:

```
import requests.exceptions

try:
    #do thing
except e if e in requests.exceptions:
    pass
```

Comment: [Pokemon](http://wiki.c2.com/?PokemonExceptionHandling) anti-pattern? Unless you can actually *handle* them all the same way, why do want to catch them all in the first place?

Comment: Well I am handling them all the same way by passing, and I only want to do this for exceptions thrown by requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the exceptions in the module `requests.exceptions` derive from the base class `RequestException`.

If you really want to catch any and all exceptions you can do so:

```py
from requests.exceptions import RequestException

try:
   # do thing
except RequestException:
   # handle exception
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this if the base class is unknown?

Comment: I'm not sure that there's a sensible way of doing this without having knowledge of the module you are working with. You could of course catch all exceptions (using `except BaseException:`) then write some handling code that checks if this exception `isinstance()` of something in the module? Then you can choose to suppress or re-raise the exception based on that. **But** that seems very hacky and probably more trouble than it is worth.